# How to send remote updates with python?

Tags: pymongo, updates

How can I send updates remotely with pymongo?

I tried several methods but failed.

```
def funksiyon(sonuc):
    db.find({"update": sonuc})
    if sonuc == "yes":
        print("Yeah. Please update.")
    else:
        print("No.")

aga = ""
funksiyon(aga)
```

Comment: "but failed" is not a problem description. Why happened? Why was that wrong? [Edit[ your question to explain your specific problem(s) and quote any error(s) received or wrong behaviours observed.

Comment: @undercore_d update in mongodb database: it says no although yes.